# How do I get out of this loop? (Java related)

Tags: java, string, loops

I am trying to code a simple game where you can choose to continue or quit at the end. I wrote this code and now I'm stuck in a loop. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Yes or No?");

            yesOrNo=input.next();

            while (!yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                    System.out.println("That is not a valid response. Please enter yes or no.");
                    yesOrNo = input.next();
            }

            if (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                continueGame=true;
            } else{
                continueGame=false;
            }
```

Comment: Review the conditions of your loop. The way they are now, you'll enter the loop no matter what the input is. You want to enter it only when the input is not "yes" AND the input is not "no".

Comment: `!yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")` <- Try to think of a value for `yesOrNo` that would result in this condition becoming `false` and your error should become obvious

Comment: `!yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")`

Answer (score 0):

**reason:**

see that the `!` changes the result of the check. Therefore if you enter `yes` the statement `yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` would be true but the statement `!yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")` would be false. Since you want to run on a `yes` do not use the `!` on this part of the check.

**solutions:**

you can either do

`while (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {` runs only if you type in yes, quits on all other words

or

`while (!yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {` runs always and quits only if you type in no

or

`while (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || !yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {` pretty much like the first one, but keeps on running on different words/typos like 'abc'

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

try using `&&` instead of `||`.

```
while (!yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
   //do something
}
```